# Use string variables in getRange method

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to invoke the following:

```
var range5 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(range1:range3);
```

where `range1 = "C590"` (string value) and `range3 = "O594"` 
(string value) (found previously in the script)

But I get the error:

> Missing ) after argument list

for the `range5` line. Is there a way to pass the two strings as the range?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the result what you want, how about modifying from ``range1:range3`` to ``range1 + ":" + range3``?

Comment: This is an example of string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

The questioner has a problem with this line of code
`var range5 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(range1:range3);`

This line of code would have worked:

`var range5 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(range1+":"+range3);`

The main thing here is how the variables are added/assigned to the command, and how the separator is added between the variables.

---

There are at least four variations for `getRange` but the most basic is "getRange ('cell/range address')". As shown above, it IS possible to join the variables and a separator to create a valid range.

But there *are* other options. In this scenario, the most obvious is `getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)`. This expects integer parameters but `getRow` and `getColumn` can be used to break down each of the strings.

The code below is an example of managing the ranges as strings.
Each string is used separately to create the parameters of the specific range.
Step#1 - The string for range1 is used in `getRange`. This permits...
Step#2 and #3 - get the row and column integers for the range.
Step#4 - Repeat for range3
Step#5 - Now we can get range5 using "getRange (row, column, num rows, num columns)". The values for this are supplied/calculated from steps#1 thru 4.

```
function so_52759685() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
    var range1 = "C590";
    var rangeone = sheet.getRange(range1);
    var rangeonerow = rangeone.getRow();
    var rangeonecolumn = rangeone.getColumn();

    Logger.log("RANGE1: " + range1 + " - row = " + rangeonerow + ", and the column number = " + rangeonecolumn); // DEBUG


    var range3 = "O594";
    var rangethree = sheet.getRange(range3);
    var rangethreerow = rangethree.getRow();
    var rangethreecolumn = rangethree.getColumn();
    Logger.log("RANGE3: " + range3 + " - row = " + rangethreerow + ", and the column number is " + rangethreecolumn); //DEBUG

    var range5 = sheet.getRange(rangeonerow, rangeonecolumn, rangethreerow - rangeonerow + 1, rangethreecolumn - rangeonecolumn + 1)
    var range5Rows = range5.getNumRows();
    var range5Columns = range5.getNumColumns();
    Logger.log("RANGE5: " + range5.getA1Notation() + " - Number of rows = " + range5Rows + ", and number of columns" + range5Columns);

}
```

---

Alternatively, one might use a **named range**.
The same process applies except that:
1 - range1 and range3 are Named Ranges, assigned to C590 and O594 respectively.
2 - Instead of declaring the string literals, we use `GetNamedRange`.

```
function so_5275968502() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
    var rangeone = ss.getRangeByName("range1");
    Logger.log("range one is " + ss.getRangeByName("range1").getA1Notation()); //DEBUG
    var rangeonerow = rangeone.getRow();
    var rangeonecolumn = rangeone.getColumn();

    Logger.log("RANGE1: " + rangeone.getA1Notation() + " - row = " + rangeonerow + ", and the column number = " + rangeonecolumn); //DEBUG

    var rangethree = ss.getRangeByName("range3");
    Logger.log("range three is " + ss.getRangeByName("range3").getA1Notation()); //DEBUG
    var rangethreerow = rangethree.getRow();
    var rangethreecolumn = rangethree.getColumn();
    Logger.log("RANGE3: " + rangethree.getA1Notation() + " - row = " + rangethreerow + ", and the column number is " + rangethreecolumn); //DEBUG

    var range5 = sheet.getRange(rangeonerow, rangeonecolumn, rangethreerow - rangeonerow + 1, rangethreecolumn - rangeonecolumn + 1)
    var range5Rows = range5.getNumRows();
    var range5Columns = range5.getNumColumns();
    Logger.log("RANGE5: " + range5.getA1Notation() + " - Number of rows = " + range5Rows + ", and number of columns" + range5Columns); //DEBUG

}
```